# Emulated app displays different version than archived app

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app that gets built and imported into xcode and when I emulate the app, my view that displays the version, displays the correct version, however once I **archive** and **export** the app for **enterprise distribution**, the view shows an old version.

**Am I supposed to run a command to make sure everything is in sync before exporting the app?**

---

**Update:**

When I build my app using `ionic cordova build ios --tagGoesHere` where `tagGoesHere` can be anything, and then export the app, and push the generated .ipa file using my MDM service, the newest version is shown.

Even stranger, when I update the .ipa file in my MDM software with the same exact .ipa file that was just displayed properly, the app reverts back to the old version.

Comment: You can try running `ionic cordova prepare ios`. This should coply all the contents of the `www` folder to the `platforms/www` folder.

Comment: The odd thing is that the `platforms/www` folder IS being updated.  I don't understand why an old version is being shown?  It's almost like on generation of the `.ipa` file, the old version is being used.  Also, the actual xcodeproj file only gets updated sometimes.  I'm not sure why

Comment: Well the xcodeproj file does not need to be updated, the only thing that needs to be updated are plugin files if you add/remove one, resource files of the plugins and the files in www. Maybe something got mixed up somewhere, try removing the platforms, plugins and node_modules folders and also remove the package-lock.json file. Then reinstall everything.

Comment: update:  when I run `ionic cordova build` if I add any tag, for instance, changing it to `ionic cordova build --new`, the new version is displayed

Comment: Thats really strange. Either something is not right in your setup or there is a bug in one of the tools. But if you do a release you add the `--prod` and `--release` flag anyway so there should be no issue, right?

Comment: When I use `--prod` it does not bundle my css properly.  There are lots of issues with it on github.  Ionic needs to get their act together